# R, operations between subset of list's vectors

Tags: r, vector

I am sure this has been asked already, but after long searching I'm still stuck...

how to calculate the element wise mean of a subset of list's vectors? the list looks like:

```
str(hold_day)
List of 365
 $ : num [1:65341] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : num [1:65341] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : num [1:65341] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : num [1:65341] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : num [1:65341] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : num [1:65341] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : num [1:65341] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

and I need to calculate the element-wise mean from, say, the [[n]] to the [[n+10]] vector of the list (and not the mean of the elements of each vector). so for example:

hold_mean =(hold_d[[n]]+hold_d[[n+1]]+...+hold[[n+10]])/11

how to calculate hold_mean recursively within a loop?

I have tried with  `sapply(hold_d, function(x){mean(x[c(n:n+10), na.rm=T])})` 
but  this only returns the elements of the vectors, not the vectors of the list.

many thanks for any advice

Comment: Does `rowMeans(sapply(hold_day, '[', 1:10), na.rm = TRUE)` do what you're looking for?

Comment: No it doesn't actually:
`a<-(hold_day[[1]]+hold_day[[2]])/2`  <br>  

`Browse[1]> summary(a)`   

`Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's`

`0.232  42.610  57.960  54.230  67.990  87.210   14219`  

`Browse[1]> b<-rowMeans(sapply(hold_day, '[', 1:2), na.rm = TRUE)`  

`Browse[1]> summary(b)`  

`Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's`  

 `NA      NA      NA     NaN      NA      NA       2`

Comment: A reproducible example with expected output would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, none of them actually worked out.
I resort to using a tensor (matrix of vectors) rather than a list. 
on the tensor, the simple `colMeans(hold_d[k:(k+md-1),], na.rm=T)` does the job.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Hadley's purrr package and the zip_n function (which is awesome btw)

```
library(purrr)
datas <- lapply(1:5, function(x) rep(x,10))
datas %>% zip_n(.simplify = TRUE) %>% lapply(mean)
```

Basically, zip_n turns the list inside out, which in this case puts all associated elements inside their own list element, as opposed to as part of a different list element. afterwards we can just calculate the corresponding means, if you want to calculate for the first 10 elements, you would now lapply over the first 10 elements of the zipped list:

```
lapply((datas %>% zip_n(.simplify = TRUE))[1:10], mean)
```